# Get Average execution time of a method C#

Tags: c#

This method works fine. But I want to know if there's any other way or make this method more accurate and my ultimate goal is to run the same method 10 times and get the average execution time of it.

```
   public static void Measure(Action action, int noOfTimesToRunThisMethod)
   {
        long averageTime = 0;

        GC.Collect();  
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();    
            
        Console.WriteLine("Started");

        for (int i = 1; i <= noOfTimesToRunThisMethod; i++)
        {
           Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();              
           action();
           watch.Stop();
           Console.WriteLine($"Attempt:{i.ToString("D2")} Time Taken:{watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
           averageTime += watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Average: {averageTime/ noOfTimesToRunThisMethod}");
   }
```

To use this helper method

```
   var noOfTimesToRunThisMethod = 10;
           
   Utils.Measure(() => 
   {  
     MyMethod(arr)
   },noOfTimesToRunThisMethod);
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: Instead of rolling your own you might want to go with something like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet). It does what you need and more. Plus the benchmark framework is easy to use and has been tested all the way through ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Benchmark](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) to test your execution method time.
there is an example of Benchmark:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<ListMemoryAllocationTest>();
    }
}
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class ListMemoryAllocationTest
{
    public int Count { get; set; } = 900000;
    [Benchmark]
    public void DefaultConstructor()
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(i);
        }
    }
    [Benchmark]
    public void AddCountToConstructor()
    {  
        List<int> secondNumbers = new List<int>(Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            secondNumbers.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Change your project configuration from `Build` to `Release` and Run project.

Result:

```
|                Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |    Gen 0 |    Gen 1 |    Gen 2 | Allocated |

|    DefaultConstructor | 753.4 us | 14.80 us | 15.20 us | 628.9063 | 627.9297 | 237.3047 |  1,024 KB |
| AddCountToConstructor | 499.6 us |  9.86 us | 17.78 us | 255.8594 | 255.8594 |  95.7031 |    391 KB |
```